# Close Unwanted Mac Terminal Windows En-masse

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript

As a system admin, I write/test/run a ton of shell scripts (typically from BBEdit). I rely on the BBEdit “Run in Terminal” drop-down menu a lot to quickly test run a script.

As a result, I end up with a ton of 'dead' (unwanted/expired) Terminal windows (i.e. executed script windows with “[Process completed]" displayed at the bottom).

Does anyone have a suggestion for how to clean-up all of these dead Terminal windows em-masse?

I can't blindly close *ALL* windows (or quit Teminal.app) because I have current SSH sessions running and other tasks in-progress. I only want to close the Terminal windows that have been executed via BBEdit and display '“[Process completed]'.

I can't set the Apple Terminal.app preference to do this for me (Terminal -> Preferences -> Settings -> Shell -> When the shell exits) because I generally want to *examine* the output returned before closing for QA purposes.

My goal is to manually run a script/command from time to time to clean-up all the Terminal windows on-demand as needed. Once I have a ton of confusing dead windows that I dont need Ill run it and then continue working in BBEdit as needed.

After a few hours of writing/troubleshooting/editing a script (or *multiple* scripts) I end up with dozens of dead Terminal windows - of which I manually close with a click and a Command + W. This gets tedious of course.

I have played around in AppleScript for something to bind to a shortcut or widget, but haven't found a solution as of yet.

Simple commands such as

`tell application "Terminal" to close (get window 1)`

aren't too helpful because I havent been able to determine which windows have an inactive state and which do not.

Thoughts? Any suggestions are appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Is there a possibility that these _Terminal_ sessions that have `exit`'ed, (i.e. those sessions you want to close that have _“[Process completed]"_ displayed at the bottom), exist in a _Tab_ of a _Window_, and  may the same Window contain other _Tabs_ with potentially other open/active sessions too?

Comment: @RobC, If a **Terminal** _window_ or _tab_ has an active process, and default settings are in play, then e.g. `tell application "Terminal" to close (every window whose processes = {})` will not close a window that has an active process. It will on close _tabs_ (and _windows_) that meet the criteria.

Comment: Downvoted for failure to _accept_ an answer. Let me know when you've accepted an answer and I'll withdraw the downvote. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Every "window" object in Terminal has a property named "processes", which is a list of the active processes for that window.

If the "processes" list is empty (in AppleScript terms, `processes = {}`), then you can safely close the window.

Therefore, an AppleScript like this should work:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    
    set windowsICanClose to (every window whose processes = {})
    
    repeat with windowToClose in windowsICanClose
        close windowToClose
    end repeat
end tell
```

You can save that as a script, put it in BBEdit's "Scripts" folder, assign it a keyboard equivalent if you like, and that should do the job.

Comment: No need for a repeat loop.

Comment: Thanks Rich. That did the trick. One of those annoying things I was too busy to 'fix'. COVID-19 has let me dig into a lot these little things and (hopefully) fine-tune my day-to-day admin workflows. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple:

```
tell application "Terminal" to close (every window whose processes = {})
```

This will close every *window* of **Terminal** that has: `[Process completed]`

---

Just to be clear.. If e.g. you have a **Terminal** *window* open with multiple *tabs*, then `tell application "Terminal" to close (every window whose processes = {})` only closes the *tabs* that have  `[Process completed]` and not any other *tab* in that *window*.  The *window* is only closed if the only *tab* of that *window* contains `[Process completed]`.  That is to say, that is the result as tested under **macOS High Sierra** anyway.

Comment: This did the trick. Wasn't using the verb has correctly in the context of AppleScript.